# cronjob reading from one database and writing to other

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a `table1` on `server1`

Every night I have to run a cronjob that would

a.) delete all contents of `table2` on `server2`

b.) read all contents of `table1` from `server1` and dump it on `table2` of server2 (`table1` and `table2` have same schemas).

Is there a way, I can do both as a SQL script. Right now, I am using python to make two database connections, read content from one and then dump into the other and running that as a cronjob.

The db is mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Could you use the [federated storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-description.html)? If yes, then you could do this in two simple sql statements.

Comment: @VMai . Not sure I can. I'll ask the IT department.. Any other way??

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way that uses pure SQL. Remember there are two different database servers included. Maybe you can convince your IT department. The user would only need execute rights for a simple stored procedure with `TRUNCATE table2; INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;`

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. SQL script would just provide you with commans to execute on the database server. You still need something to make server connections. SQL wont do that for you, that's not what SQL is meant for.

You'll need to use a client, mysql/python or whatever suits you. I'd suggest you to not complicate matters unnecessarily. What you're doing right now seems fine.