# copy tables from one database to other using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have a two databases on two servers.
I have to read some tables from database1 (server1) and dump it on database2 (server2).
I am using python  to do this.

I would like to run a SQL like

```
Insert into db2.table2 (Select * from db1.table1)
```

table1 and table2 have same schemas.

Is that achievable in python?
How do I achieve the above with two prepared cursors?

right now my code looks something like this.

```
db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.1.2.3", user="host1", passwd="pass1",db="db1")
db2 = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.1.2.4", user="host2", passwd="pass2",db="db2")
cursor1 = db1.cursor()
cursor2 = db2.cursor()
```

Comment: You can't do it with sql alone without the federated storage engine, [as I told you yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814057/cronjob-reading-from-one-database-and-writing-to-other). The fastest way to do ith without would use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE` if you're allowed to use those statements.

Comment: @VMai I cannot use  federated storage engine. I asked the IT department. I am trying to use a programming language to do it now..

Comment: What is not working - that should be allowed you are setting up 2 separate connections & 2 cursors. I've never done it with MySQL but I have with Oracle and Postgres - should work the same.